# IE9 doesn't show borders between groups in table

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-9

On a web page I have a table with rows grouped into several body sections (using `tbody` elements). Also, each column is in its own separate column group. The borders are to be drawn between these row and column groups only, so I use this construct:

```html
<table rules="groups" frame="box">
```

See [this test page](http://jsfiddle.net/ShjUC/).

Many browsers (including IE8 and below) will render it like this:

[image: Borders between groups as properly rendered by IE8]

Strangely, Internet Explorer 9 omits all borders (only the table frame is visible):

[image: For some reason IE9 displays no borders]

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried a CSS resetter?

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava, He replicated in fiddle.

Comment: As Jeremy said, did you try a [CSS resetter](http://www.cssreset.com/)?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs OK, now I tried to prepend Eric Meyer's Reset CSS (version 20110126) and it caused the inner borders to disappear altogether even on IE8.

The `border: 0` style of the `td` element in the resetter seems to be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Try border attributes together like `border:2px 1px solid blue;` in `td` and `border:2px 1px solid red;` in `th`

http://jsfiddle.net/ShjUC/2/

Hope this will help

Comment: Hmm… Although your suggested style does cause the borders to appear (as thin ones, not the 2px horizontal / 1px vertical as was intended), this CSS will not pass validation. The `border` property doesn't allow us to set different values on the four borders.